# SASS variable as style name

Tags: sass, gulp-sass, libsass

Is it possible to use a SASS variable in within a style name? If yes, what's the syntax?

I've tried the following:

```
@mixin bleed($direction) {
    margin-#{$direction}: 10px;
}
```

and

```
@mixin bleed($direction) {
    #{'margin-' . $direction}: 10px;
}
```

with no luck.

For reference, I'm using lib-sass and the error thrown is `Unknown word`

Comment: Can you provide the *actual* code that reproduces this problem?  All I see here is undefined variable.

Comment: It's sat inside a mixin with a parameter.  Updated

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a typo, your mixin doesn't have a name.  How were you intending on using it?

Comment: Editting on phone so forgot to add the name. My bad

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem then: http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/dc2cb9eca9c718bf4104

Comment: Fair enough. I figured I had the syntax correct and, as confirmed by a colleague, the mixin works on his machine. The only difference between our setups is that his version of node-sass is 3.4.0 whereas mins is 3.4.1. I doubt that's the issue though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@mixin margin($direction) {
    margin-#{$direction}: 10px;
}
```

That works for me with the following call

```
.margin-test{
    @include margin(right);
}
```

Gives

```
.margin-test {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```